# Why does archive.ubuntu.com seem to have infinitely nested "ubuntu" folders?

Tags: directory, official-repositories, ubuntu-website

If you go to the http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ site, and then just click multiple times on the `ubuntu` folder, it looks like you can't actually go into the folder. The exact same directory listing is still shown--and after every click on folder name, it will append another `ubuntu/` to the URL  shown in the address bar!

[image]

Is this a bug or a security feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither. That's just the effect of a symbolic link that points to the current directory:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ln -s . foo/foo
$ ls foo
foo
$ ls foo/foo
foo
$ ls foo/foo/foo
foo
```

It's purely for convenience of mirroring. Say we have a mirror `http://my-mirror.com`. It does not have to make a top-level `ubuntu` directory; it can simply mirror `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. Then, if you need to switch mirrors in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can directly swap `archive.ubuntu.com` with `my-mirror.com`.

Comment: It seems that it works up to 40 `ubuntu`s, and then returns 403 for any more, an I right in assuming this is a symlink limit that is there to stop people sending near infinite amounts of `ubuntu`s and DOSing the server?

Comment: @jrtapsell that's probably due to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79576/70524

Comment: Ah, my google-fu was weak, that makes sense