# How to create alias for a sub-folder to point to the parent folder?

Tags: filesystem, symbolic-link

I need to make a folder with name `./public/sop` behave like it is `./public`.

I tried `ln -s ./public/ ./public/sop` and there were no errors. But it doesn't work. `ls ./public/sop` does not show the other files/folders in the `./public` folder. It shows just one line:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 9 Nov 20 13:06 public/sop -> ./public/
```

And an attempt to `ls ./public/sop/test.txt`, where `test.txt` is an existing file in `./public`, returns `No such file or directory`.

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use just `.` as the link target:

```
ln -s . ./public/sop
```

Then `./public/sop` is effectively `./public/.`, which is just `./public` itself.

[You can see this in action](https://askubuntu.com/a/953254/158442) in [the Ubuntu repositories](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/), where [`ubuntu`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu) is a link to `.`, so going to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/whatever` is effectively the same as `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whatever`.